# How to obtain a heatmap or network diagram of variable interaction through a machine learning model

Tags: r

I try to use the "vivid" package in R to draw the correlation of variable interactions, because this package can directly analyze the trained machine learning model, and its visualization is very beautiful, but when I execute the vivi() command , I get the wrong information, I don't know what's wrong, because I can execute another instruction in the package: pdpPairs(), and get the PDPS diagram, although I know it's difficult without more information , but I'm hoping to get an answer.Or you can also tell me if there is any other way to directly analyze the trained machine learning model to get a heatmap or network diagram of variable interaction, which will be very useful to me

```
viFit <- vivi(
         fit = gbm_fit,
         data = variable_data,
         response = "Y1_learning",
         gridSize = 10,
         importanceType = NULL,
         nmax = 100,
         reorder = TRUE,
         class = 1,
         predictFun = NULL)

Agnostic variable importance method used.
Calculating interactions...
Error in mat[vars2] <- res[["value"]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Comment: a bit late. But it's hard to diagnose the issue without more information. But I will say, if youre using xgboost or a similar package, you will need to create a custom predict function to make it work with vivid. It could also be a case of using the wrong data format. vivid accepts a data frame, but it looks like you might be passing a list. see the answer here for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338823/getting-error-while-calculating-feature-importances-r

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems that it is indeed question of ‘list’ , and I will  try